# *edited -- How might I create a material like a chunky liquid?

Tags: materials

Higha blenders! I'd love to hear your ideas on how I would go about modeling and texturing a material that is made of solids and liquids, together. Like liquid with chunks. . I have tried fluids with particles, noise bumps, transparency/translucency and SSS, and can't seem to get the results I'm looking for.

I'd love to hear your approach(s).[image: gritty goo, like crystalized honey]

Comment: Final result should be a model or just a picture?

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'm very new blender and to the BSE community. I will try to be more descriptive in my questions so others can get the most out of community dialog. Cheers

Comment: @brockmann -- Hi. The final product should be a model of a substance much like crystallized honey, consisting of 2 components. grit, and goo.

Comment: This could help with model itself: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100615/how-to-cover-a-surface-with-cells-biological-tissue/100623#100623

Comment: @cgslav - Great Tip! I'll play with that today. It opens a whole new world of opportunities. I got the color of the material right, thanks to the suggestions of Volume Absorption from MACHIN3, and the metaballs were great for the random organic shapes. maybe making the "hair" metacubes of random size will get the surface crystals looking good. I will post the collective method when I get it right.

Answer (score 1):

Metaballs with displacement for the small details. Try a refractive shader like the glass shader and maybe add some volume scattering.

Comment: thanks for the tip! I have never used metaballs. found a tutorial on youtube.  I'll give it a go.

Comment: The metaballs worked great for the main "goo" shape. Sculpted from there. I'm revisiting a particle system inside for the interior crystalline structures. I seem to have a lot to learn about displacement to get the outside surface to match, and may need to shop an e-gpu as I'm working on a 2018 macbook pro. The displacement gets intense, fast (from a performance standpoint).